# Redirect dynamic url to new dynamic URL which is also prettified in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a website which has dynamic URLs and they're not currently prettified. I have re-worked the site and included pretty URLs, but the real dynamic folder structure/filename has also changed.

To better explain, the current dynamic URLs look like

http://example.com/liveguide/year.php?year=2017

The new dynamic url for the same page is

http://example.com/shows/show-list.php?year=2017

I use the following:

```
RewriteRule ^shows/(199[5-9]|200[0-9]|20[0-1][0-7])/?$ /shows/show-list.php?year=$1 [L]
```

To enable the use of pretty URLS like

http://example.com/shows/2017

So what I'm trying to do is if anyone followed a link of the original dynamic URL, they'll end up on the new clean URL. So far I've just got

```
RewriteRule ^liveguide/year.php /shows/show-list.php [R=301,L]
```

Which redirects to the correct page, but you're left with the ugly URL in the address bar. How could I do it so that the new, pretty URL is in the address bar?

Ie someone visits

http://example.com/liveguide/year.php?year=2017

They end up on, and see in their address bar

http://example.com/shows/2017

Comment: I would do this in PHP (or whatever the server-side language is) - you will have much more control of the substitution and strange cases, that you must take care of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to match the query string, which is in a separate variable, and used in a `RewriteCond`, which capture to `%1`, `%2` etc. Like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^year=(\d{4})$
RewriteRule ^liveguide/year\.php$ /shows/%1? [R=301,L]
```

While we are here, do you really need to only match just those exact years? Would it matter if `/shows/1234` also got rewritten? Probably not, you can just return a 404 from your PHP, so a simpler rule would be ok, like the above just saying any four numbers. It will also work for future years without changing it.

```
RewriteRule ^shows/(\d{4})/?$ /shows/show-list.php?year=$1 [L]
```

The goal is usually not to match exactly what you want, and only that, but rather to ensure nothing else (other parts of the site) will be matched that shouldn't be. Simpler rules are easier to maintain and review later. Your script must already be able to handle bad data anyway, so just let it handle the detailed checking without duplicating it unnecessarily.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this is better but I'm still seeing the query string in my address bar. It comes out as example.com/shows/1995?year=1995

Comment: Oops, sorry about that, I missed the `?` from the replacement to reset the query string. I added that to my answer.